# Why can't I write a general function to check if two lists are equal?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and I don't understand why I can do this:

```
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f l  
    | l==l = True
    | otherwise = False
```

But I can't do this.

```
f :: [a] -> Bool
f l  
    | l==l = True
    | otherwise = False
```

What's going on under the hood?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but it could be because of object types. Eq class has Char, Int, Float, Double etc..., but what if you had some object like House, it wouldn't know how to compare those unless you define it. Hopefully that helps. Really it seems like it would come down to the Eq class which defines `==` for just those types.

Comment: @Matt: In Haskell there is no concept called object type or object.

Comment: @jmg yea i wasn't really sure how to say it, guess you can say type or type class.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, it's types and type classes. So you'd have a `House` type that was not an instance of the `EQ` type class.

Comment: In any event, I'm confused about the details. Shouldn't it take two arguments (`[a]->[a]->Bool`)? Isn't `l==l` always true (for any `Eq`)?

Comment: As I understood it, this is just a trivial function to illustrate his issue with types rather than anything meaningful.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe It depends on the `Eq` instance. It is true, that for all auto generated Eq instances `l == l` holds, but technically nothing prevents you from writing the following instance: `instance Eq T where { _ == _ = False }`.

Comment: @jmg: technically nothing prevents this. Nothing prevents you from designing a monad that violates the monad laws, either. But you definitely should never do something like that, anyone should be able to rely on these laws, `==` should always be an equivalence relation.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe My original code is actually reverse l == l. I just took "reverse" out to simplify my code and emphasized the problem I faced.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given two values of an *arbitrary* type, Haskell does not necessarily know how to compare them for equality. `==` is only defined for types that are part of the `Eq` class.

For example, determining if two functions are equal is undecidable in general (I think).

You can compare two lists by checking if each element is equal to its corresponding element in the other list. However, this only makes sense if you can compare the elements for equality, so you have to add a constraint:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

Comment: If you consider functions to be equal if they produce the same results for all inputs, and allow that to include non-termination as a possible result, then function equality reduces to the halting problem. So yeah, undecidable.

Comment: Something reducing to the halting problem does not by itself make it undecidable. The halting problem reducing to something does make it undecidable.

Comment: @Prateek: Right, sorry. I misspoke. In this case both can be reduced to the other, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'd point you at the chapter on typeclasses in *Real World Haskell*

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html